# SHBrowseForFolder "Make New Folder" behavior in Windows XP

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am using SHBrowseForFolder with the new dialog style which gives you an 'Make New Folder' button on

I am getting some problems with this in Windows XP.

The behavior is like this:

1) First when I invoke the dialog, the behaviour is usual(i.e, It is selecting the current folder. But 
the focus is not on the tree item(dimmed).

If I click Make new folder button with this state a new folder is creating but it is not in selected 
state(i.e, When ever we create a new folder it will allow you to rename folder with the selection on 
the item and editbox).

If i select the directory(i.e, setting focus to the item) and then clicking on new folder creating folder 
in selected state.
(In Windows 8,windows 7 and Windows Vista it is working Fine)
Anyone faced this problem.

Is there any solution for this?

```
        bool GetFolder(std::string& folderpath, const char* szCaption = NULL, HWND       hOwner = NULL)
```

{
        bool retVal = false;

```
// The BROWSEINFO struct tells the shell 
// how it should display the dialog.
BROWSEINFO bi;
memset(&bi, 0, sizeof(bi));

bi.ulFlags   = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE|BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS|BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS; 


bi.hwndOwner = hOwner;
bi.lpszTitle = szCaption;

// must call this if using BIF_USENEWUI
::OleInitialize(NULL);

// Show the dialog and get the itemIDList for the selected folder.
LPITEMIDLIST pIDL = ::SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

if(pIDL != NULL)
{
    // Create a buffer to store the path, then get the path.
    char buffer[_MAX_PATH] = {'\0'};
    if(::SHGetPathFromIDList(pIDL, buffer) != 0)
      {
          // Set the string value.
           folderpath = "";
           retVal = true;
      }     

      // free the item id list
          CoTaskMemFree(pIDL);
  }

    ::OleUninitialize();

    return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your source code?

Comment: @RogerRowland `GetFolder(std::string& folderpath, const char* szCaption = NULL, HWND hOwner = NULL)
{
 bool retVal = false;

 // The BROWSEINFO struct tells the shell 
 // how it should display the dialog.
 BROWSEINFO bi;
 memset(&bi, 0, sizeof(bi));

 bi.ulFlags   = BIF_USENEWUI|BIF_EDITBOX|BIF_VALIDATE|BFFM_SETSELECTION;
 bi.hwndOwner = hOwner;
 bi.lpszTitle = szCaption;

 // must call this if using BIF_USENEWUI
 ::OleInitialize(NULL)`

Comment: @user2009877: you should edit the question and post your source code there.

Comment: I tried your code on a Windows XP system and it just works fine. BTW you should replace 'folderpath = ""' by 'folderpath = buffer'.

Comment: @MichaelWalz did you checked this code behavior on Windows 7 Os And Did you checked My this Point:                                     >>I click Make new folder button with this state a new folder is creating but it is not in selected state.     In My code if user Click "Make New Folder" then after creating New Folder Focus Must go to the Newly created Folder. In Windows 8/7/Vista it is Working Fine. Please let me know Which version of XP you are using.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: This Behavior I need because if user creates a new Folder Then It should automatically focus to that Newly created folder so that user can rename/delete that particular Folder.

Comment: Sorry, at first I didn't understand what you meant. Look at my answer below.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Cant We produce Same Result Using BFFM_SETEXPANDED??. i tried but its not Working

Comment: I wasn't aware of the BFFM_SETEXPANDED message. But it works for me under Windows XP. See my edited answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Windows XP.

Try the code below. This may be not quite what you want, it automatically expands the default folder, but at least it results in a more or less correct behaviour. I tested it on Windows XP and on Windows 7. On later versions of Windows this might not work as expected, so possibily you should check if you are running under XP and do that quirk only if you are running under XP.

```
int CALLBACK BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM pData)
{
  if (uMsg == BFFM_INITIALIZED)
  {
    HWND hchild = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_CHILD) ;

    while (hchild != NULL)
    {
      TCHAR classname[200] ;
      GetClassName(hchild, classname, 200) ;

      if (lstrcmp(classname, "SHBrowseForFolder ShellNameSpace Control") == 0)
      {
        // hchild is the handle to the ShellName Space Control
        HWND hlistctrl = GetWindow(hchild, GW_CHILD) ;

        do
        {
          // browse through all controls of the ShellnameSpace control
          GetClassName(hlistctrl, classname, 200) ;

          if (lstrcmp(classname, "SysTreeView32") == 0)
            break ;   // we've got the list control

          hlistctrl = GetWindow(hlistctrl, GW_HWNDNEXT) ;
        } while (hlistctrl != NULL) ;

        if (hlistctrl != NULL)
        {
          // get the handle to the selected item
          HTREEITEM ht = (HTREEITEM)::SendMessage(hlistctrl, TVM_GETNEXTITEM, TVGN_CARET, 0) ;

          if (ht != NULL)
          {
            // expand the selected item
            ::SendMessage(hlistctrl, TVM_EXPAND, TVE_EXPAND, (LPARAM)ht) ;
          }
        }
      }

      hchild = GetWindow(hchild, GW_HWNDNEXT) ;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}


bool GetFolder(CString& folderpath, const char* szCaption, HWND hOwner)
{
  bool retVal = false;
  // how it should display the dialog.
  BROWSEINFO bi;
  memset(&bi, 0, sizeof(bi));

  bi.ulFlags   = BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE|BIF_RETURNFSANCESTORS|BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS; 

  bi.lpfn = BrowseCallbackProc ;
  bi.hwndOwner = hOwner;
  bi.lpszTitle = szCaption;

  // must call this if using BIF_USENEWUI
  ::OleInitialize(NULL);

  // Show the dialog and get the itemIDList for the selected folder.

  LPITEMIDLIST pIDL = ::SHBrowseForFolder(&bi);

  if (pIDL != NULL)
  {
    // Create a buffer to store the path, then get the path.
    char buffer[_MAX_PATH] = {'\0'};
    if(::SHGetPathFromIDList(pIDL, buffer) != 0)
    {
      // Set the string value.
       folderpath = buffer;
       retVal = true;
    }     

    // free the item id list
    CoTaskMemFree(pIDL);
  }

  ::OleUninitialize();

  return retVal;
}
```

---

Another solution would be using the BFFM_SETEXPANDED message as shown below. In this example the "C:" folder is automatically expanded and then the "New Folder" button behaves correctly.

```
int CALLBACK BrowseCallbackProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, LPARAM lParam, LPARAM pData)
{
  if (uMsg == BFFM_INITIALIZED)
  {
    ::SendMessage(hWnd, BFFM_SETEXPANDED, TRUE, (LPARAM)L"C:\\") ;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Micheal Walz Thanks.This Only i wanted .:) :)